# Separate contents by '/' into their own columns and express them as 0 and 1

Tags: pandas

Separate contents by '/' into their own columns and express them as 0 and 1
minimal and reproducible example was prepared to solve the problem.

**input**

```
col

A

A/B

A/C
```

My desired output is as below. How can I do this using pandas?

```
A B C

1 0 0

1 1 0

1 0 1
```

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow. see the answer linked by @jezrael. In your case you can use following code `df['col'].str.get_dummies(sep='/')`